# Corrupted string in C#

Tags: c#, string

I came across *[“CorruptedString” (Solution)](http://problembook.net/content/en/Strings/CorruptedString-S.html)*. Here is following code of program from the book:

```
var s = "Hello";
string.Intern(s);
unsafe
{
  fixed (char* c = s)
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
      c[i] = 'a';
}
Console.WriteLine("Hello"); // Displays: "aaaaa"
```

Why does this program display "aaaaa"? I understand this program as follows:

1. The [CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) reserves "hello" in the intern pool (I image the intern pool as a set of strings).
2. `string.Intern(s)` actually does nothing, because the CLR had reserved "Hello" string - it just returns address of reserved "Hello" string (object s has the same address)
3. The program changes the content of the "Hello" string via a pointer
4. ??? The Hello string should be absent in the intern pool, and it should be error! But it is OK; the program runs successfully.

As I understand the intern pool, it is like some kind of dictionary of string to string. Or maybe I missed something?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
      c[i] = 'a'; Seems like you're replacing every char with the char for 'a'

Comment: Its not like a dictionary of string to string. Its more like a hashset of string

Comment: @DieterB, Yes, it replaces with 'a' character

Comment: @M.kazem Akhgary, in other words, it computes hash of "Hello" and returns address of appropriated value?

Comment: The unsafe keyword gives you a clue... :-)

Comment: (because OP asked for it directly) most downvotes you get are probably because what you asked shows that you don't understand how C# internals (or memory addressing, or simply how are the compile-time strings referenced in compiled code, so to speak) work; for me, even with no C# background, the answer to your question is obvious and directly implicated by the code itself. You can literally *always* (even CPU-based RAM protection can be circumvented by hardware hacks) inject data into given memory range; nontrivial code will use pointers to memory addresses, so you can easily hijack the code.

Comment: You turned the safety system off and then you wrote a bunch of garbage into memory you don't own.  At this point *anything can happen*, so the answer to "why did X happen?" is "X happening is consistent with *anything can happen*".  You lost the right to live in a predictable world when you turned the safety system off and then abused the privilege.

Comment: The compiler links the two "Hello" strings into the same memory location.

Comment: funny OT: this works in java as well.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

When you use "Hello" for the first time, it's interned into the application global store of strings.
Based on the fact you're executing in `unsafe` mode (more about `unsafe` [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/f0b2ed/understanding-unsafe-code-in-c-sharp/)) you obtain a direct reference to data stored in the locations originally allocated for the value of string `s`, so by

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
      c[i] = 'a';
```

you're editing what's in memory. When it accesses the store of interned strings next time, it will use the same address in memory, holding the data you've just changed. That would not be possible without `unsafe`. `string.Intern(s);` doesn't play a role here; it behaves the same if you comment it out.

Then by

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello"); // Displays: "aaaaa"
```

`.NET` looks at whether there is an entry for an address obtained for `"Hello"` and there is: the one which you've just updated to be `"aaaaa"`. The number of `'a'` characters is determined by the length of `"Hello"`.

Comment: Actually `string.Intern(s)` does nothing in this program. You can comment this line and program will works the same (because "Hello" had reserved). But I agree with you

Comment: I suppose that JIT replaces all occurences of literal by its getter to table with specified computed hash key. By that time specified value has changed

Comment: ".net looks whether there is entry for hash key obtained from "Hello" and there is." -- what? When two hashes are the same, it means Equals should be performed. I don't have an idea how it works, but I think everything is done at compile time (?). `Console.WriteLine("Hello");` -- "Hello" is just a reference to already known string.

Comment: This step is performed by JIT. At compile time you know only literals, no any mention to intern table.

Comment: @LmTinyToon valid point, I've removed part not affecting observed behavior.

Comment: Huh. Son of a JIT.

Answer (score 5):

Even though [**@Jaroslav Kadlec**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2248454/jaroslav-kadlec) answer is correct and complete I would like to add some more information about the behaviour of the code and why `string.Intern(s);` is useless in *this case*.

### About Intern Pool

Actually .NET automatically execute string interning for all string literals, this is done by using a special table that stores references to all unique strings in our application.

However it's important to notice **that only explicitly declared string are interned on the compile stage**.

Consider the following code:

```
var first = "Hello"; //Will be interned
var second = "World"; //Will be interned
var third = first + second; //Will not be interned
```

Of course in some circumstances we would like to intern  some string at run-time and this can be done by `String.Intern` after checking with `String.IsInterned`.

So coming back to the snippet of the OP:

```
//...
var s = "Hello";
string.Intern(s);
//...
```

In this case `string.Intern(s);` is useless as it's already interned at compile stage.

Comment: Important to mention about usage `string.Intern(s)`. Strings can be not interned (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.compilationrelaxationsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)